# How to write a 'safe' head in coq?

Tags: coq, proof, dependent-type

I'm trying to do something in Coq similar to [this liquid Haskell trick](https://sdleffler.github.io/LiquidHaskellLimitations/), which defines a partial function but proves it's actually total:

```hs
{-@ head :: {xs:[a] | len xs > 0} -> a @-}
head (x:xs) = x
```

Here is my first attempt, but Coq doesn't like it ("Casts are not supported in this
pattern."):

```
Definition safeHead {A : Type} (xs : list A) (nonempty : xs <> nil) : A.
Proof.
  refine (fun {A : type} (xs : list A) (pf : xs <> nil) =>
            match xs with
            | x : xs => x
            | nil => _
            end).
  (* Some tactic here to prove the hole from nonempty *)
Defined.
```

I also tried adapting option 1 from [this blog post](https://plv.csail.mit.edu/blog/unwrapping-options.html), but that fails with the same error:

```
Definition safeHead {A : Type} (xs : list A) (not_nil : xs <> nil) : A
  match xs return _ with
  | x : xs => fun _ => x
  | nil => fun is_nil => False_rect _ (not_nil is_nil)
  end eq_refl.
```

Is there a way to get this to work in coq? I'd also love to understand the error message; what is the 'cast' and in which pattern is it failing?

Comment: The cast Coq complains about is the pattern `x : xs` : in Coq, `y : A` is a way to ascribe the type `A` to the term `y`. 

The constructor for adding an element onto a list is either `cons x xs` or `x :: xs` (the latter only if you issued the command `From Coq Require Import List. Import ListNotations.` to bring the list notation into scope).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @kyo dralliam pointed out, you should use `::` and not `:` for the cons operation of lists.

The main problem with your definition is that you lose the information that `xs` is not empty when you match on it. To keep that information you must be explicit about it. Like so:

```
From Coq Require Import Utf8 List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition safeHead {A : Type} (xs : list A) (nonempty : xs ≠ []) : A :=
  match xs as l return l ≠ [] → A with
  | [] => ltac:(contradiction)
  | x :: xs => λ _, x
  end nonempty.
```

Using the `return` information of the `match` I say that I construct a proof of `l ≠ [] → A` where `l` is a local name I give to `xs` using the `as` clause.

This means that in the case `[]` we have to inhabit `[] ≠ [] → A` and thus I conclude using the `contradiction` tactic, using tactics in terms.

In the cons case `x :: xs` we don't really care about the non-empty assumption so I ignore the argument and return the head `x` as we wanted.

Finally the whole `match` expression now has type `xs ≠ [] → A` so to get `A` we must give it the `nonempty` proof.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achive this is to use tactics to write the body of the definitions

```
Definition safeHead' {A : Type} (xs : list A) (not_nil : xs <> nil) : A.
  destruct xs.
  - exfalso; apply not_nil; reflexivity.
  - apply a.
Defined.

Let xs := cons 1 nil.
Definition xs_not_nil : xs <> nil.
  unfold xs; intro; discriminate.
Defined.

Eval compute in safeHead' xs xs_not_nil.
```

Another quite simple way to achive similar behavior is to define inductive datatype for non-empty list.

```
Inductive nlist {A : Type} : Type :=
  ncons (x : A) (xs : list A) : nlist.

Let nxs := ncons 1 nil.

Definition safeHead {A : Type} (nxs : nlist) : A :=
  match nxs with
  | ncons x xs => x
  end.

Eval compute in safeHead nxs. (* 1 : nat *)
```